# getline directly to array c++, in one line

Tags: c++, getline, arrays

Is there a way of directly storing `getline` into `c char array`.

Currently, I am doing something like this...

```
istreams.getline(name, sizeof(name));
strcpy(names[i], name);
```

Is there a way of just doing it in one line, such as `istreams.getline()`.

Comment: sorry, it's c++ code

Comment: `istreams.getline(names[i], sizeof names[i]);`

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks :). Just out of interest when I return names[-1] for example, my program keeps printing out `LÁF`. Do you know why?

Comment: Because that 'text' is stored before `names[0]`. You must not attempt to access elements outside the array's bounds.

Comment: Because `names[-1]` is not part of the array, what are you expecting it to do? It doesn't give you the last element, C++ is not Python

Comment: @0x499602D2, that assumes `names[i]` is actually an array, not a `char*`, which isn't clear from the question

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. But if it is out of bounds, isn't it supposed to return `null` or am I wrong?

Comment: @Jongware if you access `out of bounds` are you expected to get random characters returned? I thought it would return `null` or something?

Comment: In C++, you are not manipulating *strings* or something like that, using `char` arrays. You instruct the computer to *show what there is in memory*. "Bounds" (and being in or out of them) are not a standard concept for C/C++ arrays. Perhaps you should use real `strings`, which shield you more from mistakes like these.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute these two lines

```
istreams.getline(name, sizeof(name));
strcpy(names[i], name);
```

for this one

```
istreams.getline( names[i], sizeof(names[i]));
```

I suppose that `names` is a two dimensional character array. Otherwise if `names[i]` is a pointer then you have to use some other value instead of expression  `sizeof(names[i])`

Also you could use `std::vector<std::string>` as a container for strings.

For example

```
while ( std::getline( istreams, name ) ) v.push_back( name );
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working in the end :). Just out of interest, is it normal to get random characters like `LAF` returned if you access `out of bounds`, such as `names[-1]`?

Comment: @Rews Prog What do you expect to get using names[-1]?

Comment: @Rews Prog You are trying to access memory that does not belong to the array. So anything that stored in this memory can be obtained or even the program can crash.

Comment: Thanks. I put `array bound checks` so that if I do put `-1` the program does not crash, but it kept returning some funny characters, so I thought I was doing something wrong. So just to clarify, it is normal in C++ for it to return funny characters if `out of bounds`?

Comment: @Rews Prog Any characters can be returned because the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Is there any way of preventing this?

Comment: @Rews Prog The only way is to write code that does not attempt to do this. C/C++ does not check array boundaries.

Comment: I did something like this... `if (i<0 || i>10) { cerr >> "Out of bounds" >> endl; else return names[i]`, and if it is `out of bounds`, it still returns random garbage like `Y*^`

Comment: @Rews Prog I do not see your code but in any case if you access out of boundaries some garbage will be returned.